# How to check if a 2D mesh is connected

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, finite-element-method

I'm trying to optimize structures by using FEM and genetic algorithms (GA), the FEM solver is a commercial one, and I'm programming the GA.

Something like [this](http://www.scielo.br/img/revistas/riem/v6n1/08f03.jpg).

My first approach is simple, just erasing elements and computing the result, but I'm getting a lot of unfeasible solutions because some parts of the mesh become disconnected.
How can I detect unconnected structures in my 2D mesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calls for some graph theory.  Begin by visiting an arbitrary vertex; add each vertex it's connected to (all the things around a face, or along edges, that include the vertex), to your itinerary.  Then visit a node in your itinerary and add its neighbors, that you haven't visited, to the itinerary.  When  you've run out of itinerary, you've found a complete connected component.  If that complete connected component doesn't cover the whole mesh, then the mesh is disconnected.

If instead you want the mesh to be fully edge-connected, use edges as the things you visit instead of vertices.

Comment: Thanks, it's just what I'm looking for. Does this algorithm has a name? It will be much easier to search about it with a name.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29 here's a starting point.  you can follow the itinerary in any way you choose; sets (which tend to produce nodes in arbitrary order) are convenient for this, but using a stack or queue give depth-first and breadth-first searches respecively.